# Package and corresponding respository

Tags: package-management

I have installed many packages in the meanwhile, also from various repositories and not only from the default ubuntu source list.

Somehow I would like to know which packages were installed from which repository. Using

```
dpkg-query -l '*'
```

I can get the package list and their details, but it does not show from which repository the packages were installed from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apt-cache policy [package name]`. Example:

```
jos@zyrrup:$ apt-cache policy indicator-weather
indicator-weather:
  Installed: 0.9-0ubuntu4
  Candidate: 0.9-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 0.9-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kasra-mp/ubuntu-indicator-weather/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kasra-mp/ubuntu-indicator-weather/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This indicates that there is a `ppa` called `kasra-mp/ubuntu-indicator-weather` containing the package `indicator-weather`.

The numbers (100, 500) indicate a relative *priority*. You could, in principle, install a package from multiple sources.  The priority indicates which source is tried first, second, etc.

Comment: what are these numbers : 500 , 100 etc?

Comment: Good point. I added an explanation.